# Good way to clean Stainless Steel Railing

Tags: cleaning, stainless

I have a stainless steel fence in my garden. Its near the sea and constantly looks dirty and old. I think the steel is a Stainless 316 as opposed to 304.

What cost effective cleaner could I use or what techniques could be the best to clean the numerous posts.

Also, Is there anything that could preserve the stainless steel from future build-up?

Comment: Is it a corrosion problem or is it grit adhering to the fence?

Comment: I would say it is salts and slight yellow colour. More adhering

Comment: Barkeepers friend is the best product out there. We bought an old stainless steel stove that was coated in grease and it cut right through it.

Comment: Many moons ago I worked in a metal fab shop which made a ton of railings and if I recall correctly, we used Turtle Wax to protect the stainless steel.

Answer (score 1):

I would add a protective coating to it.  I personally have used [Stainless Steel Defender](http://www.dfisolutions.com/products/stainless-steel-defender/).  I use this on anything from dishwashers, fridges, and bar-b-que pits when I flip a house.  I have been happy with the product but there may be other products that are better - this is the only one I have used.